# Getting error Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error. in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gradle

I would like to begin with a preface to inform you all that I have already seen almost every thread and question on this, so there is no point in linking me another thread on this.

So I have this error where I can't see anything in my layout (in Android studio). I have tried almost every solution that the internet has given me. If there is anything I may have missed and you all know, let me know. Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/firstButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="firstButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

build.gradle (Module: app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "testing.abdullah.me.testtest"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

KEEP IN MIND: I do not know much about gradle, so if it is an issue with gradle, please do not just tell me to put something in, tell me whether to put it in dependencies, buildtypes, or anything else.

Comment: you have to post the code my friend

Comment: @Psypher Code added

Comment: @AbdullahRasheed along with the code where exactly you are facing the problem ? can you be more descriptive :)

Comment: @Umair I have no clue, the items just arent showing up

Comment: @AbdullahRasheed where are the items not showing up. If it's the layout editor it's fine android studio create problems while rendering the layouts. That's why you need to find out exactly where is the problem occurring,

Comment: @Umair The layout editor isnt showing any of the items, I dont exactly know why or where the error is

Comment: @AbdullahRasheed well it can be due to 2-3 reasons. 1) android studio is not rendering the layout.
2) You have included some dependencies or support library is not loading properly.
3) Have you tried doing invalidate/restart your android studio.

Comment: @Umair what is invalidate

Comment: @Umair Also, i  just opened it in a virtual phone, and all of the items are at 0, 0

Comment: @Umair Invalidate and restart didnt fix it

Comment: @AbdullahRasheed ok can you attach the screen shot of what is happening and your log too ?

Answer (score 0):

use previous version, alpha1 instead of alpha3:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```